# Obter caminho da imagem e não blob://

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, upload, blob

Então, nós desenvolvemos um app com Cordova, e agora eu preciso fazer um upload de imagem para um webService de um terceiro. Eu instalei o cordova-plugin-camera e consigo obter uma imgem a partir da Galeria ou da Câmera, e inserir o preview no DOM. Só que a imagem no src="" vem em em um tipo blob(blob://localhost:4g5713f4g234g5a234).

Aqui tem um print dele rodando, por enquanto no emulador(https://prnt.sc/gl67f3)

Existe um método, jeito, etc para eu conseguir pegar pegar o caminho real dela e fazer para eu poder fazer o upload?

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady(){           
        /* 
            @cordova-plugin-camera 
            //cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html
        */

    function setOptions( srcType ) {
            var options = {
                // Some common settings are 20, 50, and 100
                quality: 70,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                // In this app, dynamically set the picture source, Camera or photo gallery
                sourceType: srcType,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                allowEdit: true,
                correctOrientation: true  //Corrects Android orientation quirks
            }
            return options;
        }

        function createNewFileEntry( imgUri ){
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.cacheDirectory, function success( dirEntry ){
                // JPEG file
                dirEntry.getFile("tempFile.jpeg", { create: true, exclusive: false },function( fileEntry ){
                    // Do something with it, like write to it, upload it, etc.
                }, onErrorCreateFile);

            }, onErrorResolveUrl);
        }

        function openFilePicker( selection ) {

            var srcType = Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM;
            var options = setOptions(srcType);
            var func = createNewFileEntry;

            navigator.camera.getPicture(function cameraSuccess( imageUri ){
                func(imageUri);
                displayImage(imageUri);
            },function cameraError( error ){
                console.debug("Unable to obtain picture: " + error, "app");
            }, options);
        }

        function openCamera( selection ){

            var srcType = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
            var options = setOptions(srcType);
            var func = createNewFileEntry;

            navigator.camera.getPicture(function cameraSuccess( imageUri ){
                func(imageUri);
                displayImage(imageUri);
            }, function cameraError(error) {
                console.debug("Unable to obtain picture: " + error, "app");
            }, options);
        }

        //mostra o preview
        function displayImage( imgUri ) {
            $('#js-previewFile').attr('src',imgUri).parent().addClass('is-visible'); 
        }

    /*
      actions
    */

        $('#js-openFilePicker').on('click',function(){
            openFilePicker();
        });

        $('#js-openCamera').on('click',function(){
            openCamera();
        });


    /*
      REQUEST
      esse é o código que me passaram, pra mim mandar o arquivo por ajax
    */
    var form = new FormData();
        form.append('file', file, 'file');

    $.ajax({
        async : true,
        crossDomain : true,
        url : '...',
        method : 'POST',
        headers :{
            'authorization': '....',
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            'postman-token': '...'
        },
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        mimeType : 'multipart/form-data',
        data: form
    }).done(function(r){
        console.log(r);
    }).fail(function(r){
        console.log(r);
    });
}
```

Eu consigo mandar esse Blog pelo formdata? Ou tenho que transformar antes?
Conseguiram entender o que preciso?

Comment: Here there's a print of the code running in Ripple ( http://prntscr.com/gl67f3 )

Comment: Desculpe, agora que eu vi que eu estava no StackPT (-1 merecido)

Comment: votei pra reabrir a pergunta. ps: quando a pergunta foi escrita em um idioma errado não acho necessário negativar, apesar de ser um reforço para dizer que tem algo errado, basta fechar ou ajudar o autor da pergunta traduzindo ela :) ... +1 pra pergunta

Comment: Nenhuma alma caridosa sabe como me ajudar? Eu já "consigo" pegar o arquivo da galeria/câmera, e preciso fazer um POST com AJAX passando essa imagem, para atualizar um perfil da pessoa.

Comment: @romuloinnocencio Conseguiu resolver? Caso não, posso te ajudar

Comment: Então, usando o FileTransfer, basicamente dá certo se eu mandar o ImgURI direto... consegui sim. 
`var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(fileURL,serviceURL,function( r ){
                $wp.find('.loading').fadeOut('fast',function(){ $(this).remove(); });
`

Comment: Então, usando o FileTransfer, basicamente dá certo se eu mandar o ImgURI direto... consegui sim. 
`
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
      options.fileKey = 'fotoperfil';
      options.httpMethod = 'POST';

var ft = new FileTransfer();
      ft.upload(fileURL,serviceURL,function( r ){
          //console.log('deu');
      });
`
No fileURL, eu passei direto o ImgURI(blob), mas limitei a proporção nos options com targetWidth/Height (senão dava {code:1}, arquivo não encontrado ).

Eu tava querendo fazer com ajax, mas o plugin-file-transfer já resolve o problema.